# Kafka Producer error: Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

One of my KafkaStream apps gives me the following error:

```
Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms
```

It is not likely a permission or connectivity issue. Because it consumes a batch of messages (maybe till the last message available) then I see `Informed to shut down` in logs and then `State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN`. Then I get the timeout error.
It is a simple single-threaded app with code as simple as this:

```java
builder.stream("prod.company.scores",
                    Consumed.with(ScoreSerde.getGenericKeySerde(), ScoreSerde.getEnvelopeSerde()))
                    .filter((key,value) -> isRecordNew(value))
                    .filter((key,value) -> isScoreNew(value))
                    .filter((key,value) -> isScoreRedeem(value))
                    .peek(foreachAction)
                    .to("kafka-consumer.score.redeem");
```

Comment: 9 223 372 036 854 775 807 is the maximum value a Java `long` can have. Someone might have tried to use it to mean “infinity”, just guessing. Obviously the producer has not been running for that many milliseconds.

Comment: Yes maybe that is the way their logger makes long infinity to String. Still though the point is why the Informed to shutdown part!

Comment: I don't like to add this as an answer so just comment it here as a reference for future readers. Changing the application id solved the problem.

Comment: Why do you say the message `Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms` is an error? `Then I get the timeout error.` The message only says that the producer is closed with a timeout, not that anything did time out. Is it messaged logged as ERROR level? If yes, there should be more information about the error.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax You are right it was not literally an error but still it stops my application so from my point of view it was. But technically not an error.

Comment: If there was no error, the app should not stop. It's unclear to me how changing the application.id could have solve the issue (whatever the issue is). I assume you have a shutdown hook registered to avoid auto-termination if the main() method exits?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes I have a shutdown hook, but it just closes the stream. It was odd for me too.

Comment: It happened all the time? Can you reproduce it? Maybe DEBUG logs help?

Comment: Unfortunately our Kafka cluster was upgraded, and in the new version at least, I couldn't reproduce it to see the logs.

Comment: @Hessam how did you fix the issue? any RCA?

Answer (score 0):

**INFO KafkaProducer: Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis =      9223372036854775807 ms.**  this message does not shutdown the application. Need to check for other problems.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).